# Maintain Different states in Bullhorn Rest API

Tags: php, rest, api, curl

Currently i am using Bullhorn Rest API for my client. And i have two servers,

**i) Development Server** -> Here test users entries are created for testing and checking progress will be done via Bullhorn Rest API.

**ii) Production Server** -> In this server real site users will be created and working with the site via Bullhorn Rest API.
So i need to maintain the two different states (of data or entries for candidate,job) in Bullhorn. How can we achieve this ?

Comment: Can you explain your question in brief like what issues you are facing?? what did you try??

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI http://www.bullhorn.com/ -> Bullhorn . It is like a naukri/indeed site.

Comment: I know about bull horn what is your issue and what code did you tried

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI i need to differenciate the records in bullhorn admin interface which is created by development and production server